# My LWP Script Not Working

Tags: perl, web-crawler, lwp

I am running

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
```

Comment: Do you have curl or wget installed, and do they work? If they don't work, perl won't work either...you don't have internet access.

Comment: @runrig I think so. How would I check if I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$site` has the `html` code.

Also you can use the function `getstore` to save the `html` data to a file, like:

```
my $http_code = getstore( 'http://www.google.com/', 'google.html' );
```

Comment: But how can I get the get() function to work? There is no error in my original code correct? Maybe something is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: @mtrmilk: Your code seems correct for me. What output do you expect?

Comment: Oops! I've made a mistake on my question. It actually returns "Couldn't get it! at line 6". Something is probably wrong with my confuguration. I am running this on a VMWare player running CentOS.

Comment: @mtrmilk: I've tested it and can confirm that works. So, yes, look into your configuration because the problem is in other place.

Answer (score 0):

It would help you a lot if you could see the *reason* for the failure. I suggest you use the core `LWP` instead of the simple version. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $ua->get('http://www.google.com/');

die 'Couldn't get it: ', $response->status_line unless $response->is_success;

my $site = $response->decoded_content;
print 'Got it.';
```

Comment: Okay, so the reponse was: "Couldn't get it: 500 Can't connect to www.google.com/80 (Connection refused) at Sample line 12.  What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? Does it do the same with other URLs?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have just found out!